# Constructing a GestureDetector in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, gesturedetector

I have been detecting different kinds of input with the different implemented Gesture Detector methods. I do however want to change some of the preferences of the G.D by changing the parameters of the method below:

```
public GestureDetector(float halfTapSquareSize,
                   float tapCountInterval,
                   float longPressDuration,
                   float maxFlingDelay,
                   GestureDetector.GestureListener listener)
```

I got ^ code of http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.html

I am especially interested in changing the value of "halfTapSquareSize"

How would I go about implementing that into my code below?

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements GestureDetector.GestureListener {

@Override
public void create() {
    super.create();
    //Doing stuff at create
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    super.resize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();
    //Rendering stuff
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    //disposing stufff
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
    // Doing stuff at tap
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    //Doing stuff when paning
}

@Override
public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
    return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only implements the GestureListener. This listener needs to be associated with a GestureDetector, and the GestureDetector then needs to be registered to handle input.

So within your MyGdxGame class, you'll need something like this:-

```
GestureDetector input = new GestureDetector(this); // 'this' refers to your MyGdxGame instance
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(input);
```

Now you can either supply extra arguments to GestureDetector's constructor, as you have mentioned in your post, or use the GestureDetector's relevant methods, like so:

```
input.setTapSquareSize(someFloatValue);
```

Comment: damn. It was that easy. Anyway - Thanks a lot